# Is there a way to compare 2 GitHub repositories?

Tags: github, repository, chromium

I'm trying to make my own chromium fork so that I can make a browser that suits my needs, but I don't exactly know where to start.

I know that there are many chromium forks out there, so I was going to try and compare 2 GitHub repositories, where one of the repositories would be Chromium, and the other would be Brave so that I would see what Brave changed from chromium so that I would be able to change things like the branding or UI, but I don't know how to compare 2 GitHub repositories.

I've looked around, but none of them are working, or some will work, but they are a little too complicated.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to clone both repositories locally, and then use Git or a third-party file comparison tool ([Winmerge](https://winmerge.org/?lang=en) on Windows, [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), ...) to compare the latest codebase from their respective default branch (`master` or `main`)

Git itself can show you the differences with:

```bash
cd /path/to/repos1
git --work-tree=../repo2 diff
```

Comment: @Formula1Fan43 Great, well done. Glad to have been of assistance.